# How to get byte size of request?

Tags: node.js, express

I am making an API in Node.js Express which might get large requests coming in. **I would really like to see how big the request are.**

```
//....
router.post('/apiendpoint', function(req, res, next) {
  console.log("The size of incoming request in bytes is");
  console.log(req.????????????); //How to get this?
});
//....
```

Comment: Is `req.headers['content-length']` good enough?

Comment: Awesome, that seems to be enough indeed

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You can use `req.socket.bytesRead` or you can use the [request-stats](https://www.npmjs.com/package/request-stats) module.

```
var requestStats = require('request-stats');
var stats = requestStats(server);

stats.on('complete', function (details) {
    var size = details.req.bytes;
});
```

The details object looks like this:

```
{
    ok: true,           // `true` if the connection was closed correctly and `false` otherwise 
    time: 0,            // The milliseconds it took to serve the request 
    req: {
        bytes: 0,         // Number of bytes sent by the client 
        headers: { ... }, // The headers sent by the client 
        method: 'POST',   // The HTTP method used by the client 
        path: '...'       // The path part of the request URL 
    },
    res  : {
        bytes: 0,         // Number of bytes sent back to the client 
        headers: { ... }, // The headers sent back to the client 
        status: 200       // The HTTP status code returned to the client 
    }
}
```

So you can get the request size from `details.req.bytes`.

Another option is `req.headers['content-length']` (but some clients might not send this header).

Comment: Very nice overview. If you add also `req.headers['content-length']` I can accept :)

Comment: Ok, but be aware of my annotation :)

Comment: Socket bytesRead didn't seem to work (usually gives too big values), I suppose that is because of node's socket pooling. Request-stats works nicely though.

Comment: Why is details.req.bytes always zero (0) even if I'm sending a request body or query params. I need to know the whole size of requests including the headers

Comment: Maybe you can get more details by opening an issue at the request-stats module at GitHub

Comment: `req.socket.bytesRead` gives a cumulative value, not the value of the current request.

Comment: The answer is wrong. As @JohnMeyer wrote one socket used multiple times.

Comment: This doesn't work as expected, because this will add bytes to the previous bytes read. This happens when we send parallel request to the API.

Answer (score 5):

You can not use `req.socket.bytesRead` because `socket` is reusable, so `bytesRead` is a size of total traffic passed over given `socket` and not the size of a specific request.
A quick solution that I used - a tiny middleware (I use Express):

```
const socketBytes = new Map();
app.use((req, res, next) => {
    req.socketProgress = getSocketProgress(req.socket);
    next();
});

/**
 * return kb read delta for given socket
 */
function getSocketProgress(socket) {
    const currBytesRead = socket.bytesRead;
    let prevBytesRead;
    if (!socketBytes.has(socket)) {
        prevBytesRead = 0;
    } else {
        prevBytesRead = socketBytes.get(socket).prevBytesRead;
    }
    socketBytes.set(socket, {prevBytesRead: currBytesRead})
    return (currBytesRead-prevBytesRead)/1024;
}
```

And then you can use `req.socketProgress` in your middlewares.

Answer (score 3):

Five years later, this is Google's first link for this question.

But no npm module is needed here. And `req.socket.bytesRead` number cannot be used either, because every byte read by the socket is counted, even the HTTP header. Worse, for the same socket, next requests continue to increment the value.

The best way is to use a simple counter for each chunk of data:

```
// Set up the byte counter
let byteCount = 0

// Listen the chunk events
req.on('data', (chunk) => {
    // Increment the byte counter
    byteCount += Buffer.from(chunk).length
    // Check the body byte length
    if(byteCount > REQ_BYTE_MAX) {
        // Return an error to the client
        res.writeHead(413, { 'Content-Type': 'text/plain' })
        res.end('Request content is larger than the limit.')
    }
})
```